# Rails form with checkboxes from enum (hash)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

How to create checkboxes in `form_for` from hashed `enum`:

```
class UserProfile < ApplicationRecord
  enum locations: { Kursenai: 0, Papiskes: 1, Versiai: 2 }
```

I try something like:

```
<div class="field">
  <% UserProfile.locations.map { |k, v| }.each do |key, val| %>
    <%= f.label key %><br />
    <%= f.check_box :locations, {:multiple => true}, val, nil %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

But this fails in many ways, for ex. i thought I could grab `key`from the loop and set it as a value of the label.. My Postgres has:

```
t.integer "locations", array: true
```

I also permit `locations`in strong params:

```
..permit(:locations)
```

Should there be done something else to save array in db?

Please also advice on this - now that `enum`is placed in one model but I will also use it in other classes, so should I create it as a `concern`or just as a simple class?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I do in console:

```
p = { Kursenai: 0, Papiskes: 1, Versiai: 2 }
p.map{|k,v| [k, v]}.each do |key, val| puts key, val
```

And I get:

```
Kursenai
0
Papiskes
1
Versiai
2
 => [[: Kursenai, 0], [: Papiskes, 1], [: Versiai, 2]]
```

And in template, first checkbox appears without a checkbox (just label), while last has no label. Hm...

Comment: oops, silly mistake - `map` doesn't return anything :D Better return something :) - `UserProfile.locations.map { |k, v| [k, v] }`. But this still doesn't work as expected - last checkbox's label shows full enum instead of key of one item from it. Please feel free to write a better implementation of this

Comment: Oh...... Cant belevae this.. I had `<br/>` placed there... Shame for my family...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unnecessary call to `map`.. hashes already yield [key, value] pairs while enumerating over the elements within, so you should just be able to do this:

```
<% UserProfile.locations.each do |key, val| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Also, it appears you are trying to use an `enum` column to store multiple values simultaneously, however, I believe the `enum` column helper is designed to be a wrapper around a singular value, so the form field(s) should likely be radio buttons or a `select` menu, not checkboxes.

Comment: Good point about map. That was consequence of solving previous errors. And I use enum because I use same items for select field :) Thanks!